# Fluent NHibernate Maps with ADO.NET

Tags: nhibernate, orm, ado.net, fluent-nhibernate

I have a C# .NET 3.5 data access layer that is a plain ADO.NET implementation. I'm looking to replace my sub-standard homegrown Object Relation Map classes with something more robust such as fluent-nhibernate.

I'm trying to figure out if I can use the majority of my existing ADO.NET implementation with fluent nhibernate class maps. Is it possible to use `FluentNHibername.Mapping.ClassMap` maps to map `System.Data.IDataRecord`s returned from my Database to my POCOs and to map POCOs to `IDbCommand` Update/Insert commands? Is this recommended, or am I better off using FluentNHibernate "all the way"?  I've only seen tutorials using FluentNHibernate for the entirety of the database access model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Fluent NHibernate` is only a mapping layer for `NHibernate`.  It is basically a fancy fluent style syntax to generate xml files that `NHibernate` reads/loads.

The only thing I would think you could reuse is your POCOs.  You would basically map your POCOs to the database using `Fluent NHibernate`.  `NHibernate` would then deal with all the `CRUD`.